# Нужны ли здесь запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

При этом, в большей степени за счет соединительных гаек, процесс очистки возможен даже
струей жидкости высокого давления или моющей пеной.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, здесь уточнение.